# Docker with firewall

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I wanted to filter who can access my containers and I followed this article: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host

Now the access is restricted as wanted, but the containers cannot access internet.
My rules:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  my-ip  anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

If I dump the DOCKER-USER chain, everything works well, but everyone can access my services. iptables: false is not an option in the daemon file as it also blocks some network connetion from the containers
Do you have any idea? What is not working in the containers: `curl, ping, ping IP, etc.`

Comment: Welcome to Unix.  It is best to include the version of Linux and Docker you are running. Potentially also include the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use UFW to manage the firewall, and I found this solution to be a full solution to this problem, with docker iptables option set to true: https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

Comment: I would also consider `gufw` the graphical version (unless you script it).